# What is the definition of brick product of graphs?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, definitions

Can anyone help  me with the exact definition of brick product of graphs, say path, cycle.

I am not able to find a paper with a clear definition on the internet. Can anyone give me a URL to such a paper?

Comment: It might help if you would tell us where you have found the term used.

Answer (score 3):

[On a class of Hamiltonian laceable 3-regular graphs](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(94)00077-V), contains the definition of the brick product of even cycles, with figures showing examples.

> **Definition.** Let $m$, $n$ and $r$ be a positive integers. Let $C_{2n} = 0 1 2 \ldots (2n - 1) 0$ denote a cycle of order $2n$. The *$(m, r)$-brick-product of $C_{2n}$*, denoted by $C(2n, m, r)$, is defined in two cases as follows.
>
> For $m = 1$, we require that $r$ be odd and greater than $1$. Then $C(2n, m, r)$ is obtained from $C_{2n}$ by adding chords $2k (2k + r)$, $k = 1, \dots, n$, where the computation is performed modulo $2n$.
>
> For $m > 1$, we require that $m + r$ be even. Then $C(2n, m, r)$ is obtained by first taking the disjoint union of $m$ copies of $C_{2n}$, namely $C_{2n}(1), C_{2n}(2), \dots, C_{2n}(m)$, where for each odd $i = 1, 2, \dots, m-1$ and each even $k = 0, 1, \dots, 2n - 2$, an edge (called a *brick edge*) is drawn to join $(i, k)$ to $(i + 1, k)$, whereas, for each even $i = 1, 2, \dots, m - 1$ and each odd $k = 1, 2, \dots, 2n - 1$, an edge (also called a *brick edge*) is drawn to join $(i, k)$ to $(i + 1, k)$. Finally, for each odd $k = 1, 2, \dots, 2n - 1$, an edge (called a *hooking edge*) is drawn to join $(1, k)$ to $(m, k + r)$. An edge in $C(2n, m, r)$ which is neither a brick edge nor a hooking edge is called a *flat edge*.

See also [Rainbow connection in brick product graphs](https://doisrpska.nub.rs/index.php/IMVI/article/view/4325).

> [image: Figs. 1-3: The brick products C(10,1,5), C(10,2,4), and C(10,3,5).]

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to see: *Alspach, B.*, Hamilton cycles in cubic Cayley graphs on dihedral groups, Ars Comb. 28, 101–108 (1989). [Zbl 0722.05047](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0722.05047), [MR1039136](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1039136). PDF available at [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/246354295_Hamilton_cycles_in_cubic_Cayley_graphs_on_dihedral_groups).

> Let $C_n$ and $P_n$ denote the cycle and path of length $n$, respectively.
>
> 2.1 Definition: The *brick product* of $C_n$ with $P_m$, $m \geq 1$, is denoted $C_n^{[m+1]}$ and is defined as follows. Let $V(C_n) = \{ u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n \}$, $E(C_n) = \{ u_1 u_2, u_2 u_3, \dots, u_n u_1 \}$, $V(P_m) = \{ v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{m+1} \}$, and $E(P_m) = \{ v_1 v_2, \dots, v_m v_{m+1} \}$. The vertex-set of $C_m^{[m+1]}$ [typo: should be $C_n^{[m+1]}$] is the cartesian product $V(C_n) \times V(P_m)$. The edge-set consists of all pairs of the form $(u_i, v_t) (u_i, v_{t+1})$, where $i+t \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$, and $t = 1, 2, \dots, m$. The brick product $C_4^{[5]}$ is shown in Figure 1.
>
> [image: Figure 1.]